# GCC warning about acessing bytes at offset: what is GCC complaining about?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-warnings, gcc-warning

I have an old C library that I have to build on a modern/current system. This
library has not been developed for at least 5 or 6 years (perhaps even more). So
naturally, building it with a modern C compiler throws a lot of warnings. So I
started going through the warnings and fixing the code.

But there is one warning where I really don't know what it means. I'm compiling
with GCC 9.3.0 and `-O2 -m32 -Wall` in the CFLAGS:

```
[ 17%] Building C object cu_datastructs/CMakeFiles/cu_datastructs.dir/cu_nlist.c.o
In file included from /usr/include/string.h:519,
                 from /home/shaoran/projects/cu_utils/remus_installer/cu_utils/cu_datastructs/cu_nlist.c:3:
In function ‘strcpy’,
    inlined from ‘cu_nlist_swap’ at /home/shaoran/projects/cu_utils/remus_installer/cu_utils/cu_datastructs/cu_nlist.c:389:2:
/usr/include/bits/string_fortified.h:90:10: warning: ‘__builtin_strcpy’ accessing 1 byte at offsets [-1073741824, 1073741823] and [-1073741824, 1073741823] may overlap 1 byte at offset -1073741824 [-Wrestrict]
   90 |   return __builtin___strcpy_chk (__dest, __src, __bos (__dest));
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The code in question is:

```c
int cu_nlist_swap(struct cu_nlist *nl, int id1, int id2)
{
    unsigned char *c_tmp;
    cu_nlist_names n_tmp;

    if(nl == NULL || id1 < 0 || id2 < 0)
        return 0;

    if(id1 >= nl->size || id2 >= nl->size) /* out of bounds */
        return 0;

    if(id1 == id2)
        return 1;

    c_tmp = nl->items[id1];
    nl->items[id1] = nl->items[id2];
    nl->items[id2] = c_tmp;

    strcpy(n_tmp, nl->names[id1]);
    strcpy(nl->names[id1], nl->names[id2]);   // <--- line with the warning
    strcpy(nl->names[id2], n_tmp);

    return 1;
}
```

where `cu_nlist` is defined as:

```c
// on a different .h file
#define CU_NAMELEN 1024

// ...

#define CU_NLIST_NAME_LEN   CU_NAMELEN
#define CU_NLIST_STARTCAP   2

typedef unsigned char*  (*create_f)();
typedef void    (*free_f)(unsigned char*);
typedef int     (*copy_f)(unsigned char*,unsigned char*);

typedef char    cu_nlist_names[CU_NLIST_NAME_LEN];

typedef struct cu_nlist {
    create_f         ocreate;
    free_f           ofree;
    copy_f           ocopy;
    int              cap;
    int              size;
    unsigned char**  items;  //< holds the items in the named list, initialized with NULL
    cu_nlist_names*  names;  //< holds the names for the items, initialized with NULL
} cu_nlist;
```

Am I blind? Why is the `cu_nlist_swap` generating this warning, and what does
that mean? If I remove `-O2` then the warning is not issued, I cannot understand
it. What exactly is GCC telling me?

So, the idea of this structure is to have a named list of objects, when you
append a new value, the append function checks the size. If the number of
elements (`size`) reached the maximum (`cap`), then we resize the buffers to hold
double the amount of the previous memory. This is done via this function:

```c
static  int nlist_resize(struct cu_nlist* nl)
{
    void *tmp;
    int sz;
    if (nl->cap == 0)
        sz = CU_NLIST_STARTCAP;
    else
        sz = 2*nl->cap;

    tmp = realloc(nl->items, sz * sizeof(unsigned char*));
    if(tmp == NULL)
        return 0;
    nl->items = tmp;

    tmp = realloc(nl->names, sz*sizeof(cu_nlist_names));
    if(tmp == NULL)
        return 0;
    nl->names = tmp;

    nl->cap = sz;
    return 1;
}
```

So `nl->names` points to a memory block of `1024*sz` bytes, `nl->names[0]`
points to the first 1024 bytes, `nl->names[1]` points to the next 1024 bytes,
etc. So I don't see why there may be memory that overlaps. What am I
missing here?

I know that declaring name as `char** name` and allocating `CU_NLIST_NAME_LEN`
bytes for every new name when `cu_nlist_append` is called would be better, but I
would have to rewrite a lot more of this code and this is something that at the moment I
cannot do. I know this is not pretty code and could be more efficient with the
memory usage, but I didn't write this code, I'm just maintaining it (it's legacy
code from old projects of my company that are not developed anymore). I want to
understand what GCC is warning me about.

Comment: Do you get the same warning with `-m64` ?

Comment: @PaulR yes, I get the same warning, different offsets though

Comment: `at offsets [-1073741824, 1073741823]` These offsets are strange.. :/ Are you __sure__ `nl->names[id1], nl->names[id2]` are zero terminated strings? And, as usual, would you be able to post an MCVE? Side note: `(*create_f)()` - empty braces is a function with _unknown_ number of arguments, if that's not the intention, do `(void)`. How do you allocate memory for `cu_nlist_names*  names;`?

Comment: @KamilCuk yes, they are 0 terminated strings. The function pointers are needed for object creation inside the append, it's not really important for that warning, that's why I didn't elaborate on them.

Comment: I'm not posting an MCVE because the code is clearly working and it would take me a while to create one, when what I want to understand is what GCC is warning me about.

Comment: Well, [an mcve doesn't have to be that long](https://godbolt.org/z/ox3rhs). Hm, I wonder if [it's a compiler bug](https://godbolt.org/z/PPf1Gv). As for now, I would _strongly_ advise to make `cu_nlist_names` a structure - typedef arrays are confusing and using a structure removes the warning.

Comment: @KamilCuk yes I know, I don't like typedef arrays  either, but like I said, it's not my code, I'm just trying to get this old code to work with a modern compiler with as less work as possible. This whole `cu_nlist` is huge and is used everywhere, if  I start changing the internals, then I will have to test a lot of code. I'm just fixing the obvious mistakes that GCC points out via warnings. It's just that this is a warning that I did not understand.

Answer (score 4):

One of the requirements of `strcpy()` is that source and destination must not overlap. Unfortunately, when doing its work, it also doesn't care how you've defined your buffers in memory. It continues to plough on until it encounters a zero terminator. Hence when copying from one adjacent buffer to another, it could end up overrunning if the terminating zero is not found. It might be that the inlining in `-O2` somehow exposes this threat when your buffers are adjacent (as members in `nl->names[]` are).

Anyway, I'd switch to `strncpy()` - you know your buffer lengths, it would be a trivial change and might shut gcc up.

Comment: That may me true, with `-O2` gcc seems to realize that the memory overlaps, even though it won't. by the way the append operation is constructed. That may explain why GCC is picky about that. I'll try with `strncpy` instead.

Comment: `Anyway, I'd switch to strncpy()` But note the zero terminating character handling - consider `strlcpy`.

Comment: I suspect the compiler devs treat the non-limited byte stream functions (memcpy, strcpy, scanf etc) as being deprecated cancer, so maybe it's a soft push to get you to drop them :)

Comment: @KamilCuk yes, I'm aware of that, thanks for the hint though.

Comment: Well, if I do now `strncpy(nl->names[id1], nl->names[id2], CU_NLIST_NAME_LEN-1);`, then GCC keeps complaining: `warning: ‘__builtin_strncpy’ accessing 1023 bytes at offsets [-1073741824, 1073741823] and [-1073741824, 1073741823] may overlap up to 1023 bytes at offset [-1073740802, -1073741824] [-Wrestrict]`.

Comment: @Pablo I think `memcpy` with a length of `CU_NLIST_NAME_LEN` works for now, at least for GCC up to 10.2.

Comment: @IanAbbott I didn't think about that, but `memmove` would probably be better here. I'll test with that.

Comment: Weird, gcc appears to be saying that the 1023 bytes you're trying to copy (located at the beginning of the process address space) overlaps with the entire 2GB memory space of your process. Wow.

Comment: with `memmove` (I checked it with `memcpy` as well) I didn't get a warnings. So GCC may not be happy about the overlapping memory thinking that there can be a situation where the memory will overlap.

Comment: Perhaps it thinks id1 and id2 might be equal, even though you checked for that? There should be a way to turn the warning off, since it looks like a false positive.

Comment: @user253751 yes, it looks like a false positive, but I least it got me thinking about the code and thanks to it, I now realize what it's doing. However I find the way how GCC is telling me, hard to understand. Specially the offsets, I have no idea what they mean.